# Forecast error variance decomposition

Tags: causality, vector-autoregression, variance-decomposition

[Nagayasu](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.intfin.2021.101287) uses forecast error variance decomposition (FEVD) to prove a bidirectional causal relationship between endogenous stationary variables in a two-dimensional vector autoregression (VAR). What FEVD values would indicate no causality in this framework?